# Only reading the data from one object in a nested Jsonp array

Tags: jquery, arrays, jsonp

My php file creates a jsonp response has 4 separate objects with their own nesting. I want to know how to do an $.each() through just one nesting, rather than retrieve all the values at once, because I treat each one differently. For example, I just wanna go through all the data with an $.each function that's under [SubmittedAddress]. I am calling this through an jquery ajax function. Here is the array in non-jsonp format for easy reading:

```
Array
(
    [SubmittedAddress] => Array
        (
            [address1] => 850 BRYANT STREET
            [address2] => 
            [addresscombined] => 850 BRYANT STREET
            [city] => SAN FRANCISCO
            [state] => CA
            [zip] => 94106
        )

    [CorrectAddress] => Array
        (
            [address1] => SUPERIOR COURT
            [addresscombined] => SUPERIOR COURT 850 BRYANT ST STE 306
            [address2] => 850 BRYANT ST STE 306
            [city] => SAN FRANCISCO
            [state] => CA
            [zip] => 94103
            [zip4] => 4667
        )

    [PercentMatch] => Array
        (
            [addresscombined] => 39
            [city] => 100
            [state] => 100
            [zip] => 80
        )

    [Response] => success
)
```

And here is what I got for my jsonp that's going through every single value, instead of just the values in [SubmittedAddress]

```
success: function(data, textStatus){
    $.each(data, function(index, object) {
        $.each(object, function(property, value) {
            alert(property + "=" + value);
        }); 
    });
},
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you print your array as json in php file? i mean echo json_encode( array );

Comment: Yes. I have an `if` statement in my php file that executes a `print_r` when there's no `callback=?`, to make testing easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to process one property then do precisely that, e.g.

```
success: function(data, textStatus){
    $.each(data.SubmittedAddress, function(index, object) {
        alert(property + "=" + value);
    });
    $.each(data.CorrectAddress, function(index, object) {
        console.log(property + "=" + value);
    });
    //etc
},
```

Comment: Haha! I actually tried this earlier, but I put `CorrectAddress.data` instead of `data.CorrectAddress`. Thank you!